# Error: Index of / Name Size Date Modified. Whenever trying to ftp into Linux

Tags: linux, remote, access-point, web-interface

I have set up a vsftp service on linux. It use to work perfectly fine by typing in my browser ftp://kali:@ip-address/.
However now whenever i try to do it I get the following message on the page:

Index of /
Name    Size    Date Modified

The only thing I did recently was in Esfile transfer app, in the FTP settings I added a connection to the pi (which I must say still works fine). I thought maybe this is the reason it doesn't work via the browser so I deleted it and attempted it again via the browser but it didn't work.

What does this message mean and any way I get past it ?
(I have seen this error been reported before however I am unable to solve it since they seem different)

Comment: Avoid using FTP since it's very insecure. You probably want to use something like SFTP, that is supported natively in raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error message, it's a directory index.

"Index of /" means "this is the index of the root directory".  And "Name Size Date Modified" are the column headers.

But vsftp is unable to list any files. I suspect you have a permissions or file corruption problem.